# webservice returning Object1.java not the same as Object1.java in the client app?

Tags: java, web-services, casting, object-object-mapping

The same object is defined twice in different packages:

```
packageX/Object1.java
```

and

```
packageY/Object1.java
```

[Background: `packageX` is part of a webclient service, getting objects from a server. `packageY` is a java client using the objects retrieved by this webclient service].

A function from `packageX` returns `Object1`, and the compiler throws an error when I try to use this object as an `Object1` from `packageY` (which I can understand).

=> Is mapping  `packageX/Object1.java` to `packageY/Object1.java` my only option? Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing something. Java makes things easier on the programmer by letting you use the "shorthand" of just a class's short name if you're in the same package or if you `import` the class, but each class's real name is its fully-qualified class name. In your case, you don't have `Object1` defined twice, you have one class named `packageX.Object1` and another unrelated class named `packageY.Object1`. If you try to use both in the same scope, you have to specify the entire class name for at least one of the variables:

```
import packageX.Object1;
...
private Object1 foo; // this is a packageX.Object1;
private packageY.Object1 bar;
```

There's no way to "map" from one to the other besides converting between them like you would between any two other classes that didn't have similar names.

Most likely, you should be using the same implementation in both the server and client sides. You're talking about "Web services", but this is generally only an issue if you're using Java serialization, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you use the the object of same class, which is getting returned from the webservice. No matter even if both the classes has the same structure, even then compiler will complain because the compelete class name consists of package name also.